# I need to construct function that gives out data of specific pdf function and draw histogram of it

Tags: r, probability, sampling, simulation, beta-distribution

So, the given density function is: $\theta x ^{\theta - 1}, \ \ if \ \  0<x<1 \text{ and } 0 \ \ \text{ otherwise}$. $\theta$ is given as 2. I also need to draw a line that corresponds the theoretical distribution to see whether they match.

I came up with something like this:

```
theta <- 2
izlase <- rbeta(n = 1000, shape1 = theta, shape2 = 1)
hist(izlase)
xx <- seq(0,1, by = 0.01)
lines(xx, dbeta(xx,2,1), col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

But I know that it's not correct, because I am generating a data from theoretical beta distribution and not from this particular function given. The lines function just outpots numbers from 0 to 1 linearly. I don't know how to run a simulation to get the data from the given density function and then compare it to the theoretical Beta distribution drawing over a histogram the distribution line. Anyone has any ideas?

So, here is the code, that I added:

```
     u <- runif(10000, 0, 1)
x <- sqrt(u)
hist(x, probability = TRUE)
xx <- density(rbeta(10000, 2, 1))
lines(xx, col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: So, you want to write an R method/function that is able to create samples from any form of function that you input. is that right? Or, are you only interested in creating beta distributed RVs?

Comment: No, just this one particular function I've given above. But a function that create samples from any distribution may be useful too.

Comment: The particular function is easy to solve. Not the latter one though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [inverse CDF method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) to sample from an arbitrary function, i.e. you create a uniform RV, $u$ between in $[0,1]$ and solve for $x=F^{-1}(u)$. In your case, $$F(x)=\int_0^x\theta x^{\theta-1}dx=x^\theta\bigg\vert_0^x=x^\theta\rightarrow u=x^\theta\rightarrow x=u^{1/\theta}$$
which is $\sqrt{u}$ if $\theta=2$. So, any uniform RV transformed this way will be Beta(2,1) distributed. You need to write the `R` code for it.

Comment: So, I generated random sample with numbers within (0,1) limits, that has size of 10 000. Then I draw a histogram where square root is taken from each randomly generated number and added the theoretical Beta distribution line. But obviously, it doesn't look like it should. Where is my mistake?

Comment: when you plot histogram of beta distributed variables as ```hist(rbeta(u, 2, 1), probability = TRUE)``` you'll get a very similar histogram. I think usage of rbeta and lines together is wrong.

Comment: The problem with lines is that I generated simply numbers from 0 to 1 and it doesn't show the propability for each number, but when I apply function density it does look simpilar to the histogram. Only, I don't know if it's the best, to just simply use the density function? Also, what I don't get is the limits of histogram y axis? Isn't density representing the probability that the particular number will be generated? So, how can it be over 1?

Comment: no density values don’t represent probability. You can’t sum density values for each possible x and get 1. The area under a density curve is always 1.